# При клике на map area выдавать кординаты курсора относительно блока родителя

Tags: javascript, map, img

Доброго времени! Имею ниже приведенный код на нем у нас 1 Див размером 1080х720 пкс., и в нем картинка такого же размера, на картинке через map area обозначена область для клика, при клике на которую запускается функция, выдающая координаты X\Y курсора относительно Div, но почему то она выдает Nan подскажите, пожалуйста, что я не так тут сделал?

```
<div class="glavniyblock" id="generalblock">
    <img src="<?=$bg;?>" style="width:1080px; height:720px;" id="generalblockimg" usemap="#girlonbalk">

<script>
var el = document.getElementById('generalblock');
function getmenu () {
    var clickX = (el.layerX == undefined ? el.offsetX : el.layerX) + 1;

    var clickY = (el.layerY == undefined ? el.offsetY : el.layerY) + 1;

    alert('Координаты клика: '+ clickX +' x '+ clickY);
}
</script>

    <map name="girlonbalk">
    <area target="" alt="" title="" href="javascript:getmenu ();" coords="109,140,102,165,114,182,114,196,97,206,89,240,97,259,100,283,94,316,109,352,113,411,115,456,103,474,134,479,151,473,140,428,146,379,164,316,159,286,155,253,166,224,161,204,140,188,150,172,147,150,137,143,128,138" shape="poly">
   </map>
</div>
```